# Find sum of values of a sorted dictionary and match it - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sorted dictionary of coins - each key is a Coin and the value is the number of coins available in that particular denomination. Now, given an amount, I want to take out all coins which match the exact amount(or coins which adds up to that amount, preference being performance) from the dictionary.

Here are some example scenarios:

- If I have 3 coins in the repository, with two 1p coin and one 5p coin, and if the request is for 2p, then I give back two 1p coin, and my repository has only one 5p coin.
- If I have 6 coins in the repository, with five 1p coin and one 5p coin, and if the request is for 5p, then I can give back the first five 1p coins or just the one 5p coin, which ever performs better in terms of least lookups.
- If I have 2 coins in the repository, with two 1p coin, and if the request is for one 5p, then I throw an exception saying insufficient balance.
- If I have one coin in the repository, with one 5p coin and the request is for 1p, then I throw an exception saying change not available.(Not sure whether exceptions are the right way for communicating these).

Here is the class:

```
public class CoinRepository :ICoinRepository
{
    private readonly SortedDictionary<Coin, int> repository;

    public CoinRepository()
    {
        repository = new SortedDictionary<Coin, int>();
    }

    public void Add(List<Coin> coins)
    {
        foreach (var coin in coins)
        {
            repository[coin] = repository.ContainsKey(coin) ? repository[coin] + 1 : 1;               
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<Coin, int> GetCoins(int balance)
    {
        if (repository.Count == 0)
            throw new NoBalanceAvailiable();

        //How?
        return new Dictionary<Coin, int>();
    }
}


 public class Coin
   {
     public int CoinValue { get; set; }
    //Has equals, hascode etc implemented. Omitted here for brevity.
   }
```

I'm hoping there is some LINQ extension available to solve this issue, could you please help?

NOTE:Any or all of the datastructures can be changed, only objective is to find the balance.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Is there a reason not to use simple `int` instead of `Coin`?

Comment: classic NP problem, I hope you have a short list.

Comment: @Dialectius:there could be some more features added to coin, but yes you can treat it as an integer.

Comment: It's better save total amount into a variable. In case you have insufficient balance, you don't have to loop and sum all the keys.

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution to this? I tried @Blau answer but it doesn't compile :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that coin has a property named Worth and dictionary is ordered descending by coin worth, it can be done this way:

```
public Dictionary<Coin, int> GetCoins(int balance)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<Coin, int>();

    foreach (var pair in repository) {
        while (balance - pair .Key.Worth>0 && pair.Value>0 )
        {
            balance -= pair.Key.Worth;  
            pair.Value--;              
            if (!result.ContainKey(coin.key)) result[pair.key] = 0;
            result[coin.key]++;
        } 
        if (balance == 0) break;
    }

    if (balance == 0) { 
        // pair is a struct, so repository does not change when pair.Value is modified,
        // so if we find a solution, repository has to be updated
        foreach (var pair in result) repository[pair.key] -= pair.Value;
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```